# C# .csproj build issues

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm experiencing an odd error that I can't find anywhere on google.

I have two .csproj files, one should be a .NET core library, and one should be a .NET core application (exe).

The library:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>SharpEngine</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>k4rakara.SharpEngine</RootNamespace>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <PackageReference Include="MonoGame.Framework.Portable" Version="3.7.1.189" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The app:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>SharpGame</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>k4rakara.SharpGame</RootNamespace>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <DepsFileGenerationMode>old</DepsFileGenerationMode>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <ProjectReference Include="../SharpEngine/SharpEngine.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The lib compiles just fine, but the app throws out this error, that I can only find one other case of on google, and their solution doesn't work.

```
"/run/media/disk/dev/games/SharpGame/SharpGame.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(GenerateBuildDependencyFile target) -> 
  /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly. [/run/media/disk/dev/games/SharpGame/SharpGame.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. [/run/media/disk/dev/games/SharpGame/SharpGame.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: File name: 'System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' [/run/media/disk/dev/games/SharpGame/SharpGame.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateDepsFile.WriteDepsFile (System.String depsFilePath) [0x00223] in <b62924db95114cf6bd057f9071ee911d>:0  [/run/media/disk/dev/games/SharpGame/SharpGame.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateDepsFile.ExecuteCore () [0x00007] in <b62924db95114cf6bd057f9071ee911d>:0  [/run/media/disk/dev/games/SharpGame/SharpGame.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute () [0x0002e] in <b62924db95114cf6bd057f9071ee911d>:0  [/run/media/disk/dev/games/SharpGame/SharpGame.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute () [0x00029] in <ab5fde58e30c4a00af78e61cf133d3ea>:0  [/run/media/disk/dev/games/SharpGame/SharpGame.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.103/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9] in <ab5fde58e30c4a00af78e61cf133d3ea>:0  [/run/media/disk/dev/games/SharpGame/SharpGame.csproj]
```

If a .NET guru knows how to fix this, I'd be *very* grateful. Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE:

I've managed to get it to compile by reinstalling .NET. However, it now has this runtime error, and [doesn't output a .exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIeOr.jpg) (Yes, I'm on Linux, but I thought it always just produced a mono .exe)

```
A JSON parsing exception occurred in [/run/media/disk/dev/games/SharpGame/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/SharpGame.deps.json]: * Line 1, Column 2 Syntax error: Malformed token
Error initializing the dependency resolver: An error occurred while parsing: /run/media/disk/dev/games/SharpGame/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/SharpGame.deps.json
```

## UPDATE 2:

I literally did nothing, just compiled it again, and now i'm getting the same error from before. ;-;

## UPDATE 3:

I literally ran `dotnet restore` once followed by `msbuild` and got the same error. Then, I ran it again, just for kicks, and then it worked.

Comment: Says System.Text.Json is missing, have you tried finding any info online why?

Comment: I've tried manually including System.text.json in the .csproj file, but I haven't looked online yet for why System.Text.Json might be missing.

Comment: Why do you need `DepsFileGenerationMode` property?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I added that hoping that someone elses solution would work, it doesn't help, and doesn't change the error if removed.

Comment: It sounds like you are using msbuild, have you tried dotnet build?

Comment: @Brian I haven't, however, I've managed to get it to work by using TargetFramework netcoreapp3.1, DepsFileGenerationMode old, and luck. I have no idea what I changed, but it works now.

Comment: If you're expecting it to output a standalone exe look into [PublishSingleFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables)